# How does a sum of products equal the product of sums here?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, products

**Question**

**In the attached image, they separated the summation in the second step. Is that possible?**

I think no because

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_n b_n ≠\sum_{i=1}^n a_n \sum_{j=1}^n b_n $$ for eg: $(1.1+2.2+3.3)≠(1+2+3)(1+2+3)$

**Further they also separated the limit. Is that possible?**

I think for the limit it is possible. But for the summation case it is not possible. Please explain.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Fix some $k$ and you will see that $k^2x^k$ is a common factor for all possible $l$. Thus you get common factor multiplied by a summation by $l$. Now the summation by $l$ becomes a common factor.

Comment: The left side of your equation is $n^{2}a_nb_n$ and so your calculations are wrong. I think you have edit the equation.

Comment: @KaboMurphy  sir did you are saying about the equation mentioned in image given in the link "here is image"?

Comment: No. I am talking about the equation typed in the question.

Comment: @KaboMurphy sir, still not getting.How $n^2 a_n b_n$ :-(

Comment: Your summation is w.r.t. $i$ and $j$ and the terms $a_nb_n$ do not depend on these indices. What you really wanted to type was $a_ib_j$ in place of $a_nb_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. In the first step, the example shows 
$$\sum_{l,k=0}^n \frac{k^2x^ky^l}{l!}=\sum_{l=0}^n \left(\frac{y^l}{l!}\sum_{k=0}^n k^2x^k\right)=\left(\sum_{l=0}^n \frac{y^l}{l!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n k^2x^k\right)$$
(Think about this: on the LHS each combination of $(l,k)$ is considered, and on the RHS each combination of $(l,k)$ is also included too.)

**Remember, $l,k$ are independent.**

In the second step, the limit can be separated since $\lim_{a\to a_0,b\to b_0} a\cdot b=\lim_{a\to a_0} a\cdot\lim_{b\to b_0} b$

Comment: Sir but $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_n b_n ≠\sum_{i=1}^n a_n \sum_{j=1}^n b_n $$ for eg: $(1.1+2.2+3.3)≠(1+2+3)(1+2+3)$

Comment: @Akash Patalwanshi $\sum_{i,j}^n i\cdot j=1\cdot1+1\cdot 2+1\cdot 3+2\cdot1+2\cdot2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 1+3\cdot2+3\cdot 3$. $i,j$ are independent!!

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi You could accept the answer if you'd like to. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first line summation is actually a double summation in the sense that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k,\ell=0}^{n}\left(\frac{k^{2}}{x^{k}}\cdot\frac{y^{\ell}}{\ell!}\right)=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^{2}}{x^{k}}\cdot\frac{y^{\ell}}{\ell!}=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\frac{y^{\ell}}{\ell!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^{2}}{x^{k}}.
\end{align*}